# Print first and last datatime for every ip adresses

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have var/log/messages like:

```
Nov  9 09:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.100 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.100 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:47 jenkins dhclient[921]: bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 6195 seconds.
Nov  9 11:22:02 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.100 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 11:22:02 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.100 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
```

And I need print result like:

```
192.168.0.100
first datatime: 2013-11-09 09:38:45
last datatime: 2013-11-09 11:22:02
```

How split my ip addresses, i know. But how can I print that, it's a problem for me. I did a for loop which have every ip in my list of ip`s. So I have only this:

```
str=( $(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' messages | sort -u )  );
for X in "${str[@]}"
do
 echo "$X"
 #print first data
 #print last data

done
```

Comment: i did that, thx

Comment: `2013-11-09` is not in input so you are expecting change in date format as well?

Comment: yes, i expect this

Comment: Your inputs only provide month and day. Are you assuming the current year is the year? Because nothing in your input indicates the correct year would be 2013

Comment: Iterating over each IP and scanning the file will be expensive. Consider writing small AWK to find min/max for each IP. Date formatting will be painful. Can you generate the log with "good" YYYY-MM-DD ?

Answer (score 0):

As dash-o says, you have to reformat the date. The `date` command is able to do that.

For avoiding an expensive scanning of the logfile for every IP, you can also sort the logfile by IP and time.

Finally, for generating the output, `awk` is the best tool.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="messages"

while read line; do       # reformat output of log file

  day=$(date -d "${line:0:6}" +%Y-%m-%d)
  hour=${line:7:8}
  ip=$(echo "$line" | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}')
  echo $ip $day $hour
                          # output IP, day and hour, space separated
done < $logfile | 
                          # sort this output, first by IP, then by date and time
sort |
                          # redirect sorted output to awk to format results
awk '
  { 
    if ($1 != current_ip) {
      if (last_datatime) {
        print "last datatime:  " last_datatime;
        print " "; /* empty line before new IP, remove code if not needed */
      }
      current_ip = $1; 
      print current_ip; 
      print "first datatime: "$2" "$3;
    } 
    last_datatime = $2" "$3; 
  }

  END {
    print "last datatime:  "last_datatime;
  }'
```

Comment: Given that most date strings are the same, possible to improve performance by eliminating repeated calls to `date` by comparing with last value. Instead of `day=...`, use `next_day=${line:0:6} ; [ "$next_day" != ${prev_day} ] && day=$(date -d "$next_day" +%Y-%m-%d) ; prev_day=$next_day`. On my machine, for 100 lines with same date, runs about  50X faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your log files are consistent with few lines for each IP.

We can use the following `awk` script:

No sorting required, the timestamps are in the order they registered in log for each ip. The ip lines can be mixed.

From question, year is not in input, hard coding current year.

Better pass currYear with input variable! `awk -v currYear=2019 -f script.awk input.log`

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN { # pre processing before reading input file
    currYear=2019; # hard code the current year, better provide as an input variable
    # define array for 12 months
    months["Jan"]="01";months["Feb"]="02";months["Mar"]="03";months["Apr"]="04";months["May"]="05";months["Jun"]="06";months["Jul"]="07";months["Aug"]="08";months["Sep"]="09";months["Oct"]="10";months["Nov"]="11";months["Dec"]="12";
}
/DHCPREQUEST/ { # process only lines having "DHCPREQUEST"
    ip = $10;  # extract ip variable from 10nth input
    if (ip in seenIpArr) { # if ip was seen already
        lastSeenIpArr[ip]++; # increment counter array for each seen ip, in lastSeenIpArr array
    } else { # if first time seeing this ip
        seenIpArr[ip] = lastSeenIpArr[ip] = 1; # register this ip in seenIpArr, reset this ip lastSeenIpArr to 1
    }
    ipTimeArr[ip,lastSeenIpArr[ip]] = $1OFS$2OFS$3; # save the current ip timestamp
}
END { # post processing after reading input file
    for (i in seenIpArr) { # for each seen ip (not ordered)
        printf ("%s%s%s", ORS, i, ORS); # print newline, current ip, newline
        split(ipTimeArr[i,1], a); # split the current ip first timestamp fields into array a
        printf ("first datatime: %d-%d-%02d %s%s", currYear, months[a[1]], a[2], a[3], ORS); # print the formated timestamp
        split(ipTimeArr[i,lastSeenIpArr[ip]], a); # split the current ip last timestamp fields into array a
        printf ("last datatime: %d-%d-%02d %s%s", currYear, months[a[1]], a[2], a[3], ORS); # print the formated timestamp
    }
}
```

#### input.log

```
Nov  9 09:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.100 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.100 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:47 jenkins dhclient[921]: bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 6195 seconds.
Nov  9 07:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.101 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 07:38:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.101 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 07:38:47 jenkins dhclient[921]: bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 6195 seconds.
Nov  9 09:38:46 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.100 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:46 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.100 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:38:48 jenkins dhclient[921]: bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 6195 seconds.
Nov  9 11:22:02 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.100 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 11:22:02 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.100 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:39:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.0.101 port 67 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:39:45 jenkins dhclient[921]: DHCPACK from 192.168.0.101 (xid=0x2edb1fe2)
Nov  9 09:39:47 jenkins dhclient[921]: bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 6195 seconds.
```

#### runnig:

```
awk -f script.awk input.log
```

#### output:

```
192.168.0.100
first datatime: 2019-11-09 09:38:45
last datatime: 2019-11-09 09:38:46

192.168.0.101
first datatime: 2019-11-09 07:38:45
last datatime: 2019-11-09 09:39:45
```